# Login at a API with PHP and Codeigniter failed

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

i try to login into a external API with this code, but i get no response (nothing).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain/rest/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);// set post data to true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PW");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($json);
die("Stopp");
```

What i do wrong? Or is there a better / easier way to do the login?

Update
in the meantime i've change the code to this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://shop.mydomain.com/rest/');        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=myapiuser&password=myapiuserpw");   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $errors = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        echo"<hr>";
        var_dump($json);
        echo"<hr>";
        var_dump($headers);
        echo"<hr>";
        var_dump($ch);
        echo"<hr>";
        var_dump($errors);
```

i recieve this on callup the function

string(0) "" 
array(30) { ["url"]=> string(33) "https://shop.mydomain.com/rest/" ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" ["http_code"]=> int(200) ["header_size"]=> int(499) ["request_size"]=> int(170) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.275712) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.00649) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.009913) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.035844) ["size_upload"]=> float(37) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(134) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(37) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.275399) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(13) "3.122.214.243" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(443) ["local_ip"]=> string(13) "192.168.48.28" ["local_port"]=> int(54111) ["http_version"]=> int(2) ["protocol"]=> int(2) ["ssl_verifyresult"]=> int(0) ["scheme"]=> string(5) "HTTPS" } resource(6) of type (Unknown) string(0) ""

Comment: Wha is the API reponse ? Your log are not an error

Comment: there is no real response, like i wrote at the end of my updated post i get "resource(5) of type (Unknown) " as result

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$data = array('username' => 'MY_USERNAME', 'password' => 'MY_PW');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

instead of :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PW");
```

if it's a client auth, use that :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

We need more informations to help you, what king of API, ...
Dont forget to close the post and accept the answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: hi, it wont change anything. I have updated my post yet, may you can have a look at this?